# Fetching distinct values from a collection in knockout binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, breeze, hottowel

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: hearings">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="foreach:Appeals">
                <span data-bind="text:CaseId">
                </span>,
           </td>

       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

In the above HTML, hearings is an observableArray which contains the results of a breeze query that fetches records from Hearing entity.Hearing entity has got a collection property

```
public ICollection<Appeal> Appeals { get; set; }
```

That is why I have used another foreach:Appeals in my html to fetch CaseId from that entity. But the appeals collection can have multiple entries for same CaseId.

How can I show just the distinct values of CaseId from the Appeals collection ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Appeals` and `CaseId` are observables, you would create a computed observable to extract the `CaseId` values and return an array of distinct values:

```
this.distinctCaseIds = ko.computed(function() {
    var caseIds = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.Appeals(), function(appeal) {
        return appeal.CaseId();
    });
    return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(caseIds);    
}, this);
```

You could then bind to this list quite simply:

```
<td data-bind="text: distinctCaseIds().join()"></td>
```